# Why won't LESS work on IE8?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, less

I've been playing for a while now, but cannot get LESS working on IE 8!
I've made a very simple page to test it with.

**Here is the HTML...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/v1.less">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/less.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>hello world!</body>

</html>
```

**Here is the LESS...**

```
@base_colour:red;

body {
  background:@base_colour;
}
```

**This works with Firefox, but not on IE 8.**

*jQuery is working fine as I tested changing the background with `$('body').css()` and it worked in  IE 8 no problems.*

I tried adding `type="text/css"` to the link tags and going back to old school doctype, but it makes no difference.
Any pointers?

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors? [Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512(v=vs.85).aspx) to information about the F12 developer tools. I'm pretty sure they are available in IE8.

Comment: Yes, they are available but don't show anything. No JS errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On lesscss.org in the head section you can read

> LESS runs on both the server-side (with Node.js and Rhino) or client-side (modern browsers only).

I think that IE8 is not a modern browser. ;)

Here's an interesting info:
http://starikovs.com/2012/11/27/does-less-js-support-ie-9-at-least/

The author of LESS says:

> IE9 is not officially supported – it may or may not work.

Comment: Internet Explorer was never modern, I doubt it will ever be. Microsoft simply doesn't care a bit about it. As for IE9, found [this interesting article](http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/). :)

Comment: Ok. Looks like I'm going to have to compile server side then. Cheers all.

Comment: If you use Windows, I recommend WinLess for server-side compiling. ;) It compiles files automatically after you save any changes.

Comment: I never had issues with IE8, when we were using LESS 1.3.  However, after upgrading to LESS 1.5, IE8 no longer works, and gives JS errors.

Comment: I had the same issue, I wanted to use client side LESS while testing. I managed to get it working by just including [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim). No idea if it will work with complex LESS files but seems to be working OK on mine.

Comment: @ScottRippey Thanks for that. At least I now know I wasn't going mad.